# SQL Server 2005 on laptop. Not sure if I can delete

Tags: windows-vista, sql-server-2005

I have SQL Server 2005 on this laptop. I probably got installed along with Visual Studio.

The thing is, I don't use it and it's constantly running. Process Explorer reports that it has a virtual Size of 1.5 GB.

I want to uninstall this, but I'm not sure if there are any other processes dependent on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using any SQL Server database functionality in any of your projects/ installed products, it should be fine.

In case something complains, and you have to keep it, but you want a smaller footprint, you can try the SQL Server 2005/2008 Express. That is what I use on all my development machines, and it is a complete substitute for SQL Sever pro.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have any database applications running then it's probably safe to uninstall it. From your question I'm assuming that you haven't set up anything.

If you find something that requires a database server you could install [Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=220549B5-0B07-4448-8848-DCC397514B41&displaylang=en) which should take up less resources.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I set all the SQL services to disabled when I am not using them.

If you use it occasionally, you may want to do the same. If however, you never use it, it will be safe for you to uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by turning off the SQL Server services, that should kill most of the memory footprint.

Comment: Indeed, running only the SQLExpress only when you need it can hugely help keep memory footprint low.